# Is there a better way to write code that test a value against a bit mask with ignoring selected bits?

Tags: c#, bitmask

So the following code runs through all values in a byte (0-255) and prints values that fit in the specified bit mask. Normally this wouldn't be a problem (since a regular "value & mask" only checks for set bits), but since I want to ignore some bits and make sure some are zero, the code that checks for that, ended up seeming a little long and not efficient.

I'll explain a little more details on the code.
The bit mask I used to test the code is the following: 0-1--10-

Dashes mean bits that are ignored. To find what bits should be ignored I split the mask in code into two separate masks. The first one is "mask" variable, which holds the bits that should be set. The second mask "ignore" has the bits cleared that should be ignored. This way the code can distinguish a cleared bit from one to ignore in "mask". The values I used are 00100100 (36) for mask and 10100110 (166) for ignore.

The code does correctly return expected values:

> 0x24
>   0x25
>   0x2C
>   0x2D
>   0x34
>   0x35
>   0x3C
>   0x3D
>   0x64
>   0x65
>   0x6C
>   0x6D
>   0x74
>   0x75
>   0x7C
>   0x7D

Is there any way to make this code more efficient and possibly even have just one mask to test the value with?

```cs
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte mask = (byte)(Int32.Parse(textBoxMask.Text));
            byte ignore = (byte)(Int32.Parse(textBoxIgnore.Text));

            ushort i = 0;
            byte val;

            while(i <= 0xFF)
            {
                val = (byte)i;

                if (((val & ignore & mask) == mask) && ((~(val) & ~(mask) & ignore) == (~(mask) & ignore)))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:X}", val));
                }

                i++;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```cs
if ((val & ignore) == mask)
```

...gives the same output.

---

I think your terminology might have been making this more seem more complicated.  `ignore` should be called `mask` because you're using it to mask out (with zeroes) the bits in `val` that are unimportant.  What you're calling `mask` is the expected result of that operation.

```cs
byte expected = 0b_0010_0100;  // was mask
byte mask = 0b_1010_0110;      // was ignore

// ...

if ((val & mask) == expected)
```

---

As for being more efficient, this a negligible optimization in terms of execution but it's a *big* improvement in readability/comprehension.  I'm not familiar with any techniques that would allow you to get rid of the loop, especially if you're accepting values from the user, so I'm thinking this is about as good as you're going to get.